# Object Filter In Angular/Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, object

I have the following object which i'm displaying in table format 'Key' and 'Value' headers.

```
 {
        "ab": "a val",
        "bc": "baa",
        "kk": "try",
        "dd": "again"
 }
```

I need to filter as soon as I enter some text in the input field.

So if I enter **'a'** in the input field then it should return/display in table the following as it has matching records with **'a'** either in key or value -

```
{
            "ab": "a val",
            "bc": "baa",
            "dd": "again"
}
```

I'm using ngFor in html -

*ngFor="let item of obj | keyvalue"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p5r8qk)
Basically object isn't very good way of storing arrays better transform it into actual array with structure like:

```
{ key: string, value: string }[]
```

This will enable you to use array filter and integrates smoothly with angular ngFor.

In component:

```
  /** Fixed structure or some logic that will transform your data into it like for exampe reducer */
  list = [
    { key: 'ab', value: 'a val' },
    { key: 'bc', value: 'baa' },
    { key: 'kk', value: 'try' },
    { key: 'dd', value: 'again' },
  ]

  /** Search phrase that will be used for filtering your data set */
  phrase$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

  /** Observable for filtering out data to show in table */
  items$ = this.phrase$.pipe(
    map((phrase = '') => phrase.length > 0
      ? this.list
        .filter(({ value }) => value.indexOf(phrase) >= 0).slice(0)
      : this.list
    )
  )

  /** pushing new phrase values */
  onChange(e) {
    this.phrase$.next(e);
  }
```

In template

```
Enter search phrase: <input (keyup)="onChange($event.target.value)">
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of items$ | async"><th>{{ item.key }}</th><td> {{ item.value }}</td></tr>
</table>
```

If you need logic for transforming data into array:

```
list = Object.entries(data).reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
  result[key] = value;
  return result;
}, {})
```

Comment: I know, using array it is possible or work around array.

In my case I have a long data in a object. I do not want  it to transform as it will create a performance issue. So just checking if can be done in object it self.

Comment: @Kanchan at some point it will have to be converted to array to filter out data either by filter or reduce methods of Array object so im not sure where do you want to cross the line

Comment: Okay .. This is what I wanted to hear. Without array it can't be done.

Comment: @Kanchan just to be clear you wouldn't need array if filtering would be done on server side then probably [keyvalue pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) would be of some use too you

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a custom pipe that filters the result. Note that you might need to set the property "pure" in the pipe- directive settings or else the filter will not be reapplied if an item is added to the table while on the same page. Also note that this option is not good for performance, so make sure you need it.

Comment: Pipe is place to keep the filter logic. My question is about logic.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use angularJS in Javascript for an that functionality. You need to create an app module and a controller that gets the input of the user, then looks through the array and filter out the results.

Comment: It is not recommended to use AngularJS in Angular. Avoid complicating your codebase by including multiple frameworks. This could lead to many unforeseen issues further down the line. There are many other ways one can achieve the above result in Angular. Creating a pipe or filtering in your component as explained in the accepted answer are two of them.